# Responsive iframe only works Youtube and not Vimeo

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, youtube, vimeo-player

**Edited: Inserted Snippets as suggested.**

After countless posts and tutorials: I've managed to get the following code doing what I need but only with Youtube Embedded videos:

```css
#container {

      width: 100%;
      height: 1px;
      position: relative;
    }
    #navi,
    #infoi {
      width: 60%;
      height: 60%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }
        #closeB {
            position: fixed;
            top: 28%;
            left: 79%;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border: 0;
            cursor: hand;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: grey;
        }
        video-responsive {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 56.25%;
            padding-top: 60px;
    }
        .video-responsive iframe {
        position: fixed;
        top: 30%;
        left: 20%;
        width: 60%;
        height: 60%;
        border: 0;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
    
                  <div id="infoi">
                        <div class="video-responsive">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" gesture="media"  allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>                      
                      <button id="closeB">X</button>
    
          </div>
    </div>
```

This code does what I want with a Youtube Video:

1. Floats the video above everything else
2. It's in the middle
3. It's responsive in all screen sizes
4. The close button sticks on the upper left corner of the video (over
   it) in every window resize I attempt.

However as soon as I change the video source to Vimeo (`<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/148751763"`)
It doesn't work anymore (the close button wanders around from the iframe, it doesn't stick to the corner as with the youtube embed)

Snippet2:

```css
#container {

      width: 100%;
      height: 1px;
      position: relative;
    }
    #navi,
    #infoi {
      width: 60%;
      height: 60%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }
        #closeB {
            position: fixed;
            top: 28%;
            left: 79%;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border: 0;
            cursor: hand;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: grey;
        }
        video-responsive {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 56.25%;
            padding-top: 60px;
    }
        .video-responsive iframe {
        position: fixed;
        top: 30%;
        left: 20%;
        width: 60%;
        height: 60%;
        border: 0;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    
                  <div id="infoi">
                        <div class="video-responsive">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/148751763" gesture="media"  allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>                      
                      <button id="closeB">X</button>
    
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet

Comment: Edited, thank you. Youtube content doesn't work inside snippet but the responsiveness is  preserved while it doesn't work on the second snippet, just changing the source to Vimeo.

Answer (score 0):

Are You talking about this?

https://codepen.io/Rishab2019/pen/NWGgYBX

```
  <div id="container">

  <div id="infoi">
     <div class="video-responsive">
   <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/148751763" gesture="media" 
  allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  </div>                      
  <button id="closeB">X</button>

      </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
  #container {

  width: auto!important;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;

}
#navi,
#infoi {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
    }
  #closeB {
   position: fixed;

   left:61.3%;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   border: 0;
   cursor: hand;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: grey;
    }
   .video-responsive {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;


   }
    iframe {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   }
```

Comment: that way the button is not at the upper right corner. if you "left: 71%" the button (so it is at the corner) and you resize the window you will see it wandering around. Of course if you set it in the middle it will always stay in the middle since 50% is the same for the iframe and the parent container or window. And that's my present fix but it is ugly, the conventional UI is for it to be at the corner not the middle.